# is there a less sloppy way to write this code? and how do i accept only 8 digit numbers in the last part. Need to gather data and append it to file

Tags: c#

```
        int valg = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if(valg == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" first name: "); 
            string fnavn = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------");
            Console.WriteLine(" last name: "); 
            string enavn = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------");
            Console.WriteLine(" postcode"); 
            int postnummer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine(" 8 digit phone number: "); 
            
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
       
    }
}
```

}

i know there are better ways to do some of the stuff, but im doing it based on what ive learned but kinda hit a stop. When asking for number i want to accept only 8 digit number, and somehow only accept it if the number isnt already used in my text file. Anyone have an idea as to how i could do it?

Comment: Read the line a a string and then test the string length.

Comment: There are many ways to do this (e.g. regex, etc.). The internet and stackoverflow is full of such examples. The idea is not to do the work for you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Phone numbers can contain separators, e.g.

```
(555)123-45-788
+7 555-67-98-999
12-34-56(add. 6)
```

etc. So I suggest reading the string and then extract numbers while checking their quantity:

```
string phoneNumber = "";

do {
  phoneNumber = string.Concat(Console
    .ReadLine()
    .Where(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9')); 
}
while (phoneNumber.Length != 8);
```